# Android GraphView y-axis not incrementing correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-graphview

I'm currently developing a simple Android app that uses the `GraphView` library to create a `BarGraphSeries` and I've noticed a strange occurrence when I'm plotting my data.

I'm returning a count for data that's stored in my local `SQLite` database and whenever I pass these values to the graphs y-axis the y-axis is incrementing by 0.5 but if I were to hard code the values (for the sake of testing) the y-axis is incrementing by 1 (desired functionality).

**Code that's giving me issues:**

```
    // This is how I've declared my variables... I will then go onto call my db
    // and populate each variable with a column count.

    private static int GREAT_COUNT = 0;
    private static int GOOD_COUNT = 0;
    private static int MEH_COUNT = 0;
    private static int FUGLY_COUNT = 0;
    private static int AWFUL_COUNT = 0;

    GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.graph);
    BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, GREAT_COUNT),
            new DataPoint(1, GOOD_COUNT),
            new DataPoint(2, MEH_COUNT),
            new DataPoint(3, FUGLY_COUNT),
            new DataPoint(4, AWFUL_COUNT)
    });
```

**Graph generated from passing in a variable to the DataPoint:**

[image: Undesired graph]

**Hard coded values (chart works fine):**

```
    GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.graph);
    BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 2),
            new DataPoint(1, 3),
            new DataPoint(2, 7),
            new DataPoint(3, 10),
            new DataPoint(4, 11)
    });
```

**Graph generated from hard coded values:**

[image: Desired graph]

I'm new to `Android` development and I've been doing this to help out a friend for an assignment. Am I doing anything wrong in the declaration of my `int` variables and this is why it's causing it to increase the y-axis by 0.5 whereas the hard coded values appear to increment as I would have expected in whole numbers.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what your problem is. Please give an example of desired graph and the graph that you get.

Comment: @Psytho I've updated the question with two headings above each of the images within the post (I assume you can see this). Basically the first image is a graph generated with variables passed as the y-axis and the second image is generated with hard coded variables for the y-axis.

Comment: Your graph generation is very obscure. How do you generate it? There are  values 2, 7, 10, 11, 12 which are desirable as you say but they are not in your hard coded values.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Psytho I literally just add the series to the graph by calling graph.addSeries(series). I didn't think this part of the graph generation was relevant because it's straight forward. My question is about the plotting points not the generation of the graph itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The y-values of the grid lines are generated automatically depending on minimal and maximal values of the Y-axis and it doesn't matter that you graph values are `int`. You Y-axis starts with 2 and ends with 4 and there are four "sections". So the lines are set on 2.5, 3.0 and 3.5.

- You can use [setMinY(0)](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/Viewport.html#setMinY-double-) to set zero as starting point for the Y-axis, then you will have grid lines on 1, 2 and 3.
- You can use [setNumVerticalLabels(1)](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/GridLabelRenderer.html#setNumVerticalLabels-int-) to have only one grid line, it would be on 3 in your case. But note that is your max Y values is 5 , then the grid line would be on 3.5

Maybe there is a method which allows to set grid lines only on integer values but I didn't find it.